# Increment working very strangely

Tags: c++, increment

This program is supposed to give to the last 100 digits of any size factorial. However, there's something weird going on with the counter2++ in main(). counter2 is incremented +1 for each time the loop runs in the main() function (which is 99 times). However this is what is displayed:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
71
86
90
123
164
196
207
254
300
362
432
471
551
620
630
708
761
772
857
896
985
1036
1100
1116
1207
1209
1280
1356
1417
1452
1512
```

Counter2 ends up being 1512 instead of 100, but if I remove either mult(i) or carry() from main() then it displays 100. Why does counter2 end up being 1512 and not 100?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numbers[100];
int counter2 = 0;

void init(){
//sets elements 1-99 of numbers[] to 0, increments counter2 by 1, sets numbers[0] = 1
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        numbers[i] = 0;
    }
    numbers[0] = 1;
    counter2++;
}

void mult(int x){
//multiplies each element by 1 through n to calculate for !n
//this is used to represent a very large number without using a BigInt library
//the nth element is a placeholder for the n+1 position of the number
//e.g 2nd element represents 100-900 of the number, 4th represents 1000-9000, etc
//carry() is used to take care of overflow, so that it's only 1 digit per element
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        numbers[i] *= x;
    }
}

void carry(){
//in order to make previous function work, this adds any overflow to the next
//element. e.g: 8 * 4 = 32, 3 is added to numbers[i+1], sets numbers[i] to 2
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (numbers[i] >= 10){
            counter = numbers[i] / 10;
            numbers[i+1] += counter;
            numbers[i] = numbers[i] % (counter * 10);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    init();
    for (int i = 2; i < 101; i++){
    //calculates the last 100 digits of !100, but counter2 ends up being 1512
        mult(i);
        carry();
        counter2++;
        cout << counter2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, why does counter2 = 1512? Why is it incrementing strangely?

Comment: There's no other output, it has to do with memory as others are saying.

Comment: What's your platform/compiler? Using Win7+MinGw, the output I get is from 2 to 100

Comment: Also win7+mingw, strangely enough

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are writing past the end of the `numbers` array in `carry()`:

```
        numbers[i+1] += counter;
```

Here, `i` can be `99`, in which case `numbers[i+1]` is out of bounds.

Technically, this is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What happens in practice is that you overwrite the `count2` variable, which happens to sit in memory right after the array.

One nasty thing about memory bugs is that they can go symptomless for a long time, and then surface in the worst possible circumstances. [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) is a great tool for detecting problems of this type.

Comment: Why is that affecting counter2 though?

Comment: Also in `mult` called from `main`, when `i` is 100.

Comment: @Seb `counter2` is quite possibly adjacent to the array in memory, so a write outside the array may write `counter2`.

Comment: I see, so it's merely a coincidence? Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @Seb: The hard thing to understand about **Undefined Behavior** is that undefined means **undefined**. Completely unexpected things may happen. So the right question is: *why should it not affect `counter2` ?* since the specification says anything can happen...

Comment: just curious, how to avoid this ?

Comment: @Seb: Memory bugs are like this. They can manifest themselves in seemingly strange ways. Often the symptoms are completely divorced from the actual problem.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Easy: don't write past the end of allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
 numbers[i+1] += counter;
```

you are writing out of bounds of array `numbers[100];`
when `i == 99` thus changing the value of `int counter2 = 0;` which (in your case, but not necessarily) sits right next to numbers in memory.